# Rails delegate update call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates

I have two models:
`User` (email:string)
`Profile` (name:string)

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile   
   delegate :name, :name=, :to => :profile   
end
```

```rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`rails c`

```
u = User.new 
u.build_profile         #=> init Profile
u.name = 'foo'
u.email = 'some@ema.il'
u.save                  #=> both User and Profile are saved

u.name = 'bar'
u.save                  #=> true, but changes in Profile were not saved!

u.email = 'new@ema.il'
u.save                  #=> true, new User email was saved, Profile - still not!

u.name                  #=> 'bar', but in database it's 'foo'
```

Why the Profile is not being updated(saved only for the first time)? How to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ArcaneRain, you should add the 'autosave' option on your relationship instead of adding a callback for that:

`has_one :profile, :autosave => true`

you should also investigate the 'dependent' options.
More info here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference

Answer (score 1):

This question looks familiar :)

Just tried this and it works:

```
after_save :save_profile, :if => lambda {|u| u.profile }

def save_profile
  self.profile.save
end
```

Sidenote:

I advise you to add some [default scope](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class) to always load the `profile` along the `user` if you often use both models.